# Testing for mutual bilateral one-to-one connections

Tags: mysql

So, I'm noodling around with an idea for fun and I came up with a bit of a head-scratcher. The scenario I am imagining would be sort of like the scoring after speed dating. If both parties answered yes, they get notified otherwise, nothing. This has nothing to do with dating but it was the best analogy I could come up with. There's a second pairing which is similar but I'll try to explain the data structure I am considering first.

The situation would be a table, let's call it `objects`, another table, which for the sake of argument we shall call `quiz`, and a third table which has three fields forming a composite key `objects-id-from`, `objects-id-about`, and `quiz-id` which I guess we call `answers`. `quiz` has a field `quiz`.`quiz-id` which allows a row to be paired with a second row (each would have the id of the other) - that or a fourth table called `pairs` (two fields as a composite key).

I want to then search and find, for a given set of `objects-id` all cases where either both have an entry about the other for a given quiz-id (mutual) or one has an entry for a given quiz-id and the other has a reciprocal entry for another (paired) quiz-id (paired).

In real-world terms, the mutual is like speed-dating results but the paired is more like teenagers asking their friends "who would you give a back-rub to" and then "who would you receive a back-rub from?" Again, that's not quite what we are doing but it is a lot simpler to explain it that way.

I would like to identify the mutual and paired results in a single (or at most two - one for each) MySQL statement(s). I'll drop to PHP if I have to but I'd like to show off and get the results in a single hit. The trouble is I cannot figure out how to do that.

I got as far as wondering if for the mutuals I could do an `INNER JOIN` all the way from `objects`, via `answers`, to `quiz` and back through `quiz` back to `objects`. Which feels messy but would probably work. I guess I could pair the `quiz` with a key join to `quiz` and have an extra `INNER JOIN` but I got to wondering if there was not something simpler that I was missing?

For example, is there a simpler entity-relationship pattern I could use. Is there an easier algo for getting the pairs and mutuals?

Example data:

```
objects: 
id
1,
2,
3,
4

quiz:
id/pair
1/null,
2/3,
3/2,
4/null,

answers:
from/about/quiz
1/2/1,
2/1/1,
3/1/1,
4/2/1,
2/4/1,
1/2/2,
2/1/3,
```

Thus `objects` 1&2 and 2&4 have a **mutual** for `quiz` 1

Also `objects` 1&2 have a **paired** via `quiz` 2&3 (a one-way connection, you might say)

Comment: It would greatly help your question if you could show us what your data actually looks like, via a sample input/output table.

Comment: Let me see if I can make a table for you. (Apparently SO does not support tables, so I learned something new today). The only data that really matters at this stage are the relationships formed by the IDs from table to table.